# Can't reinstall a package once node_modules is deleted

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

When I git clone a project and execute `npm install`, I can get the following (example) packages installed.

```
...
├─┬ chocolate@1.1.0
│ └─┬ white-chocolate@1.1.2
...
```

I remove `node_modules` directory and `npm install` again without changing a thing, and then the dependency package `white-chocolate` is invalid.

```
...
├─┬ chocolate@1.1.0
│ └─┬ white-chocolate@ invalid
...
```

I first found about this while trying to figure out why I can't `docker run` a container with a message that `white-chocolate` could not be found when I didn't get such a message when trying to run it locally.

```sh
Error: Cannot find module 'white-chocolate'
Require stack: <files in the project>
```

I used node on version v15.4.0. If anybody has any idea on what is going on or what I want to check, that'd be so much helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such package on npmjs. https://www.npmjs.com/package/white-chocolate

Could it be that the repo you cloned actually includes a `node_modules/white-chocolate` module that's checked in? It's an atypical way to share a private dependency, but a plausible reason for this scenario.

Comment: Hi, I renamed those packages because the parent package contains my team name (so it isn't actually `chocolate` or `white-chocolate`) I double checked that the equivalent of `chocolate` is valid in a private npm space, and `white-chocolate` in npm. `white-chocolate` isn't directly listed in package.json. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I used incompatibly high node version. After downgrading it, I could install white-chocolate